# Bad request Json to Flask ajax

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, request

My Jquery code:

```
    var obj_submit = {
        email_p : $($('.form-group').find("input[name='email_p']")[0]).val(),
        email_a : $($('.form-group').find("input[name='email_a']")[0]).val()
    }
    var json_submit = JSON.stringify(obj_submit);
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json_submit
```

My python code:

```
`@app.route('/admission', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def admission():
form = FormFieldsAdmissao()
 print (request.is_json)
content = request.get_json()
print (content)
return 'JSON posted'`
```

in the browser console I receive: `GET [...] 400 (BAD REQUEST)`

(the number of questions on the same subject is impressive, it makes me think it was something that should be simpler, since everyone has questions about it)

Comment: What is the value of `json_submit`?

Comment: share python function

Comment: the value of `json_submi`t is:`JSON.stringify(obj_submit);`  which in turn is:var `obj_submit = {
        email_p : $($('.form-group').find("input[name='email_p']")[0]).val(),
        email_a : $($('.form-group').find("input[name='email_a']")[0]).val()
    }`

Comment: my function:

`@app.route('/admission', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def admission():
    form = FormFieldsAdmissao()
     print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print (content)
    return 'JSON posted' `